# save attributes after create new layer

Tags: java, save, coordinates, geotools

I have written a method that calculates a centroid using an inner buffer and adds it to my map. The generated point layer is displayed on the map, but when exporting, I noticed that no attributes are being exported. I need a way to save at least the coordinates in the attribute table.

```
/*
     * Erstellung eines Inneren Puffers mit anschließenden Schwerpunkt für einen
     * ausgewählten Layer. Diese Daten sind aus etlichen Internetforum
     * zusammengebaut. die Methode hat leider, so vermute ich es, probleme mit
     * bestimmten geometrien und somit entstehen Lücken in der Berechnung Variante 1
     */
    public void InnerBufferCentroid() throws Exception {

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Wählen Sie einen Layer aus:");
        List<Layer> layerList = map.layers();
        String[] layerNames = new String[layerList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < layerList.size(); i++) {
            layerNames[i] = layerList.get(i).getFeatureSource().getName().toString();
        }
        String selectedLayer = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, label, "Layerauswahl",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, layerNames, layerNames[0]);

        FeatureLayer selectedFeatureLayer = null;
        for (Layer layer : layerList) {
            if (layer.getFeatureSource().getName().toString().equals(selectedLayer)) {
                selectedFeatureLayer = (FeatureLayer) layer;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Layerauswahl abgeschlossen");
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = (SimpleFeatureSource) selectedFeatureLayer.getFeatureSource();
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures();
        SimpleFeatureIterator featureIterator = featureCollection.features();

        // Erzeuge eine Liste aus den berechneten Zentroiden
        List<Point> centroidList = new ArrayList<Point>();

        // Berechne für jedes Polygon im Layer den Zentroid
        int featureCount = featureCollection.size();
        int currentFeature = 0;
        while (featureIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Verarbeite Feature " + currentFeature + " von " + featureCount);

            currentFeature++;

            SimpleFeature feature = featureIterator.next();
            // Überprüfung des Arbeitsfortschrittes
            System.out.println("Processing feature with ID: " + feature.getID());
            Geometry geometry = (Geometry) feature.getDefaultGeometry();

            double originalArea = geometry.getArea();
            double bufferArea = originalArea;
            Geometry buffer = geometry.buffer(0);
            while (bufferArea >= originalArea * 0.05 && bufferArea > 0) {
                buffer = buffer.buffer(-500);// aus Performancegründe habe ich mich für 500m Schritte entschieden. Bei
                                                // der Größe werden noch für jeden Polygon Zentroide gerechnet, aber die
                                                // Berechnung dauert nicht zu lange
                bufferArea = buffer.getArea();
            }

            Point centr;
            if (buffer instanceof Polygon) {
                centr = ((Polygon) buffer).getInteriorPoint();
            } else {
                MultiPolygon multiPolygon = (MultiPolygon) buffer;
                int numGeometries = multiPolygon.getNumGeometries();
                Polygon largestPolygon = null;

                double largestArea = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < numGeometries; i++) {
                    Polygon polygon = (Polygon) multiPolygon.getGeometryN(i);
                    double area = polygon.getArea();
                    if (area > largestArea) {
                        largestArea = area;
                        largestPolygon = polygon;
                    }
                }
                centr = largestPolygon.getCentroid();
            }
            centroidList.add(centr);
        }
        System.out.println("Zentroide berechnet");

        // Erzeuge ein Feature Collection aus den berechneten Zentroiden
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder featureTypeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        featureTypeBuilder.setName("Centroids");
        featureTypeBuilder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        featureTypeBuilder.add("centroid", Point.class);
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = featureTypeBuilder.buildFeatureType();
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType);
        SimpleFeatureCollection centroidFeatureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection();
        for (Point centroid : centroidList) {
            featureBuilder.add(centroid);
            SimpleFeature centroidFeature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
            ((DefaultFeatureCollection) centroidFeatureCollection).add(centroidFeature);
        }
        System.out.println(centroidFeatureCollection.size());
        // Erzeuge einen Layer aus den Zentroiden
        DefaultFeatureCollection defaultFeatureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection(null, featureType);
        defaultFeatureCollection.addAll(centroidFeatureCollection);
        FeatureSource featureS = new CollectionFeatureSource(defaultFeatureCollection);
//          Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("Centroid", Color.RED, Color.RED, 0.5f, 5);
        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureType);
        Layer centroidLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureS, style);
        System.out.println("zur karte hinzufügen");

        // Füge den Layer dem Map Content hinzu
        map.addLayer(centroidLayer);
        System.out.println(map.layers());
    }
```

That was my first attempt. At this point, no attributes are being passed, so I am exporting an empty geometry.
After that i tried this:

```
// Erzeuge eine Liste aus den Attributen für die Punkte
        List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = new ArrayList<AttributeDescriptor>();
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Centroids");
        builder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        GeometryType geometryType = DataUtilities.createType("centroid", Point.class, CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        builder.add(geometryType);

        // Erstelle die Feature-Typ-Definition
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
        // Erstelle die Feature-Collection
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", featureType);

        // Erstelle eine SimpleFeatureBuilder-Instanz zum Erstellen von Feature-Objekten
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType);

        // Iteriere über den centroidList und erstelle für jeden Punkt ein Feature-Objekt
        for (Point centroid : centroidList) {
            // Setze den Wert für das Attribut "centroid" im Feature-Objekt
            featureBuilder.set("centroid", centroid);

            // Erstelle das SimpleFeature-Objekt
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

            // Füge das Feature der Feature-Collection hinzu
            featureCollection.addFeature(feature);
        }

        // Füge die Feature-Collection dem Layer hinzu
        FeatureLayer centroidLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);

        // Füge den Layer dem Map Content hinzu
        map.addLayer(centroidLayer);
```

```
     // Erzeuge eine Liste aus den Attributen für die Punkte
        List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = new ArrayList<AttributeDescriptor>();
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Centroids");
        builder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        GeometryType geometryType = DataUtilities.createType("centroid", Point.class, CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        builder.add(geometryType);

        // Erstelle die Feature-Typ-Definition
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
        // Erstelle die Feature-Collection
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", featureType);

        // Erstelle eine SimpleFeatureBuilder-Instanz zum Erstellen von Feature-Objekten
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType);

        // Iteriere über den centroidList und erstelle für jeden Punkt ein Feature-Objekt
        for (Point centroid : centroidList) {
            // Setze den Wert für das Attribut "centroid" im Feature-Objekt
            featureBuilder.set("centroid", centroid);

            // Erstelle das SimpleFeature-Objekt
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

            // Füge das Feature der Feature-Collection hinzu
            featureCollection.addFeature(feature);
        }

        // Füge die Feature-Collection dem Layer hinzu
        FeatureLayer centroidLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);

        // Füge den Layer dem Map Content hinzu
        map.addLayer(centroidLayer);
```

```
     // Erzeuge eine Liste aus den Attributen für die Punkte
        List<AttributeDescriptor> attributes = new ArrayList<AttributeDescriptor>();
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("Centroids");
        builder.setCRS(CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        GeometryType geometryType = DataUtilities.createType("centroid", Point.class, CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
        builder.add(geometryType);

        // Erstelle die Feature-Typ-Definition
        SimpleFeatureType featureType = builder.buildFeatureType();
        // Erstelle die Feature-Collection
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", featureType);

        // Erstelle eine SimpleFeatureBuilder-Instanz zum Erstellen von Feature-Objekten
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(featureType);

        // Iteriere über den centroidList und erstelle für jeden Punkt ein Feature-Objekt
        for (Point centroid : centroidList) {
            // Setze den Wert für das Attribut "centroid" im Feature-Objekt
            featureBuilder.set("centroid", centroid);

            // Erstelle das SimpleFeature-Objekt
            SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);

            // Füge das Feature der Feature-Collection hinzu
            featureCollection.addFeature(feature);
        }

        // Füge die Feature-Collection dem Layer hinzu
        FeatureLayer centroidLayer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);

        // Füge den Layer dem Map Content hinzu
        map.addLayer(centroidLayer);
```

I put this together from many possible sources, but I keep getting the error

"The method addFeature(SimpleFeature) is undefined for the type DefaultFeatureCollection."
or
The method createType(String, String, String) in the type DataUtilities is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class<Point>, CoordinateReferenceSystem)

i dont know how to fixed that.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are importing the wrong types again - [DefaultFeatureCollection](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/DefaultFeatureCollection.html#add-org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature-) does have an `add` method.

While the other error:

> The method createType(String, String, String) in the type DataUtilities is not applicable for the arguments (String, Class, CoordinateReferenceSystem)

seems clear enough. [`createType`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/index.html?org/geotools/feature/DefaultFeatureCollection.html) takes 2 or 3 strings not a string and 2 objects.  So the line

```
GeometryType geometryType = DataUtilities.createType("centroid",
   Point.class, 
   CRS.decode("EPSG:25832"));
```

could be something like:

```
GeometryType geometryType = DataUtilities.createType("centroid",
   "fid:String,the_geom:Point:srid=25832");
```

But that method returns a completely different type (`SimpleFeatureType`).

But in general users shouldn't be using low level methods like this to generate FeatureTypes, it is much better practice to use [`SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.html) especially in your case the [`add`](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.html#add-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) method, which would make your code look like:

```
builder.add("centroid", Point.class, "EPSG:25832");
```

Comment: ah thanks i found my mistake^^

Comment: don't forget to accept and upvote answers that are helpful